# Php retrieve XML elements and edit file on server

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've searched and tried a number of examples and answers I've found here, but I think my requirements are quite specific and I haven't been able to find an answer that's worked for me so far... Bodging a number of answers together hasn't worked either!

Aim - Update the `hosplist_divert` value of the same element that contains a specific `name` tag.

The XML file is hosted in a sperate folder to the php page, in those case at /data/hospitals2.xml

My XML is like so:

```
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name>UHSM Wythenshawe</name>
    <hosplist_divert>1</hosplist_divert>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
```

There are approx 50 `Placemark` entries in the file.

So far I am only able to return all the hospital names from the file with,

```
// Create the SXE object
// You can read from file using the simplexml_load_file function
$url = "http://www.patientpathfinder.co.uk/user/nwasdos/data/hospitals2.xml";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, TRUE);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('hospital','http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2');

// Fetch the right HOSPITAL using XPATH
// hospital name stored in Document/Placemark/name
// dovert status stored in Document/Placemark/hosplist_divert

//trying to find above values for UHSM Wythenshawe

$result=$sxe->xpath('//hospital:name[.="UHSM Wythenshawe"]/parent::*');
  foreach ($result as $hospital)
 {
   echo $hospital . "<br>";
 }

// Update the values you want
//$target_hosp[0]->hosplist_divert = 'ON DIVERT';


// Store the updated values in the $xml variable
//$xml = $sxe->asXML();

// Print the updated XML
//echo $xml;

}
```

It took me about half a day to realise that I needed to define the namespace, but haven't really had time to understand why the namespace is required and would be happy to remove it from the XML file in. Favour of a working solution.

Thanks to all that contribute,
Nick

Comment: Apologies, the line to return all hospital names that does work is `$result=$sxe->xpath('//hospital:name');`

Comment: `//hospital:name[.="UHSM Wythenshawe"]../hospital:hosplist_divert`

Comment: Thanks splash, my research suggests that `//` is inefficient as it searches the whole file, as the scheme is known in this case, is there are more efficient way?